# jquery on external frame

Tags: jquery, lightbox, external

I think I used to use live() for this, but I have a lightbox which opens an external html page. I want to do some jquery on this page, is there a way to do this using the scripts from the parent page?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is if you add the jquery code in the external page,

otherwise, you could try:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#elemen').live();
```

But it has to be same domain